# $mdToast same attributes showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have designed a mdTast for show up tow toast at the same time, but Only the action has the passed values, other values remain as first toast.

See the photo[image]

See my code

```
      var setToaster = function(text,action,url,position) {
        var toast = $mdToast.simple()
            .textContent(text)
            .action(action)
            .position(position)
            .hideDelay(false)
            .highlightAction(true)
            .highlightClass('md-accent')// Accent is used by default, this just demonstrates the usage.
            // .position(pinTo);

      return  $mdToast.show(toast).then(function (response) {
            if (response == 'ok') {
                $location.url(url);
            }
        });
    };

    var setToaster2 = function(text,action,url,position) {


    if (vm.viewForm == false) {
        setToaster('Your Client History Form still not completed,Please Compelete it', 'Complete', '/client-history', 'top right')
    }


    if (vm.myVar.complete_profile == true) {
       setToaster('Your profile is incomplete, Please Complete your profile', 'Go To Profile', '/user/profile', 'bottom right')
    }
```

What is the problem with this function, does toast support to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I use to call the function is overriding the previous call.I have changed it to this way.It worked for me.Hope this will help someone.

```
enter code here     if (vm.myVar.complete_profile == false) {
        var message = 'Your profile is incomplete, Please Complete your profile';

        $mdToast.show({
            template: '<md-toast id="profile-message" layout="column" layout-align="center start"><div class="md-toast-content">' + message + '<md-button ui-sref="app.auth_profile">Complete</md-button></div></md-toast>',
            hideDelay: 10000,
            position: 'top right',
            parent: '#content'
        }).then(function(){
            location.url('user/profile')
        });

    }

    if (vm.viewForm == false) {
        var message = 'Your Client History Form still not completed,Please Compelete it';

        $mdToast.show({
            template: '<md-toast id="form-message" layout="column" layout-align="center start"><div class="md-toast-content">' + message + '<md-button ui-sref="app.auth_client-history">Complete</md-button></div></md-toast>',
            hideDelay: 10000,
            position: 'top right',
            parent: '#content'
        }).then(function(){
            location.url('client-history')
        });
    }
```